# Webview won't receive getStringExtra from previous activity

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, barcode, getstring

I'm trying to use a barcode scanner and then take that input and use in another activity to open with a url. I've been able to get the data to return, just not in another activity and haven't seen any projects exactly like this. I'm not sure if it has to do with intent or how I'm calling the string. The webview in the second java works but doesn't take the string. Thanks for the help!

Scanner.java (which works okay)

```
package com.pangolin.rollin.ts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Scanner extends Activity {
TextView tvStatus;
TextView tvResult;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanner);
    Button websku = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsku);
    websku.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myintent = new Intent(Scanner.this, Websku.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
        }
    });

    tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    Button scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);

    // in some trigger function e.g. button press within your code you
    // should add:
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR:" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }

        }
    });

}

// In the same activity you’ll need the following to retrieve the results:
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            tvStatus.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"));
            tvResult.setText(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            tvStatus.setText("Press a button to start a scan.");
            tvResult.setText("Scan cancelled.");
        }
    }
}

}
```

And websku.java (doesn't work, supposed to take results from previous activity.

```
package com.pangolin.rollin.ts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Websku extends Activity {
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String sku = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_websku);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_sku);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if (progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_websku);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://m.radioshack.com/radioshack/catalog/searchList.do?categoryId=&keyword="+sku);

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set any extra to `Websku` intent:

```
websku.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myintent = new Intent(Scanner.this, Websku.class);
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
});
```

Should be:

```
websku.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent myintent = new Intent(Scanner.this, Websku.class);
        myintent.putExtra("somename", somevalue);
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked great just had to add the putExtra intent, easy to overlook the simple things.. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the extras for the websku Activity. Save the intent returned from the scanner:

```
private Intent mWebskuIntent;
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        mWebskuIntent = intent;
        // more of your code
```

Then when you start the websku Activity make a copy of the saved intent which will copy also the extras returned from the scanner:

```
Intent myintent = new Intent(mWebskuIntent);
myintent.setClass(Scanner.this, Websku.class);
startActivity(myintent);
```

You might want to check for mWebskuIntent being null as well.